# Fibonacci polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci polynomials are defined by the recurrence relation:
$$
F_{n+1}(x)=xF_{n}(x)+F_{n-1}(x)\, .
$$
with $F_1(x)=1$ and $F_2(x)=x$. How can I prove:
$$
F_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor} \, {n-j-1 \choose j}\, x^{n-2j-1}\, .
$$

Comment: By checking that the second expression fulfills the same recurrence relation as the first one, and the values of $F_1,F_2$ agree.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I know the second expression is correct but I need to know how to prove it. I saw a proof for it in http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00026-014-0242-9 but i didnt understand it.

Comment: I just told you how to prove it: check that the sequence of polynomials given by the last expression fulfill the first recursion.

Comment: I think checking sequence is not sufficient for proofing a theorem. Please see The  springier link that  I wrote to understand what I mean. I can proof it with induction on $n$ but I want to find a direct proof.

Comment: So you know how to prove it with an elegant, straightforward way, but you are looking for something messier and clumsier? If two sequences fulfill the same recursion and have the same initial elements, they are the same sequence. It *is* sufficient.

Comment: Did you see the  springier link that I wrote?

Comment: To which purpose? I know what Fibonacci polynomials are.

Comment: @Amin23 Jack D'Aurizio has already shown you a clear way to prove this. If you're asking specifically about a clearer explanation of the paper you linked, then you should say so explicitly (but that goes beyond just asking "how do I prove this?"). Besides, the paper is behind a paywall, all I can see is the abstract.

Comment: In this article in Proposition 2.1, there is a proof for this function. I couldn't understand it, If it is possible please see it and tell me how it was proved? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-inductive way, just to meet OP's tastes. Any sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ fulfilling
$$ a_{n+1} = x a_n + a_{n+1} $$
has the characteristic polynomial $p(z) = z^2-xz-1$, whose roots are given by $\frac{x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2} $.

So we have the closed formula:
$$ a_n = \alpha\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}\right)^n + \beta\left(\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}\right)^n $$
with $\alpha,\beta$ depending on $a_0,a_1$. In our case $\alpha=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}$ and $\beta=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}$, so:

$$ a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}\right)^k \left(\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}\right)^{n-1-k}.$$
The coefficient of $x^m$ in $a_n$, that is a binomial coefficient, can be recovered from the last formula or by differentiating $m$ times the closed formula. Anyway, the inductive approach is elegant and way shorter. Still another way is to exploit the generating function:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}F_n(x) t^n=\frac{t}{1-xt-t^2} $$
then computing $[x^m]F_n(x)$ as: 
$$[t^n][x^m]\frac{t}{1-xt-t^2}=[t^n]\left(\frac{t}{1-t^2}\right)^{m+1}=[t^{n-m-1}]\frac{1}{(1-t^2)^{m+1}}.$$
Binomial coefficients arise since
$$ \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+k}{k}z^n $$
by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), for instance.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to show that how the  binomial coefficient of my question can be recovered from the $a_n$.

Comment: @Amin23: do you know the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(1-t)^\alpha}$? If so, my last update provides a neat explanation for the appearance of such binomial coefficients.

Comment: Thank you so much for your constructive and nice answer. Please excuse me If my comment was not clear that what I mean.